# Stop word from being split up

Tags: html, css

I'm using the following code to create what's in the image:

```html
    <h2>
        The Clore Prize <span style="text-decoration: underline; color: rgb(247, 147, 30);">i</span>mag<span style="text-decoration: underline; color: rgb(85, 81, 163);">i</span>nat<span style="text-decoration: underline; color: rgb(238, 65, 34);">i</span>on lab
    </h2>
```

[image]

The problem I want to get around is the text wrapping on the word "imagination". How can I do this?

The various span's within the word are adding the coloured dots but it causing the word to be split.

The client wants to keep the coloured dots at all costs so it's not an option to take the spans out.

---

Don't think this is a duplicate of another question as that answer requires scroll bars... which I absolutely don't want!

Comment: So, you want to be like the image?

Comment: What browser does this ? The text from this html should not wrap.

Comment: Doesn't wrap in Chrome, but I suspect your sample HTML is missing something because that styling wouldn't cause your 'i's to have 2 colors either...

Comment: Replicate the issue on jsfiddle.net, it looks like there's some styling which isn't expressed in the snippet you shared.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use

`word-break: keep-all;`

```html
<div style="width:200px;margin:0 auto;word-break:keep-all;background:#ccc;padding:0px 5px;">
    <h2>
        The Clore Prize <span style="text-decoration: underline; color: rgb(247, 147, 30);">i</span>mag<span style="text-decoration: underline; color: rgb(85, 81, 163);">i</span>nat<span style="text-decoration: underline; color: rgb(238, 65, 34);">i</span>on lab
    </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: On, phpFiddle.org the original code makes the words go in a straight line.

Comment: This solution is good, though it applies styling to all words in the block. Also, it might be simpler to apply it to the heading tag.

Comment: Removing word-break from that snippet also causes it not to wrap.  So something else is doing it.  I tested to by removing styles altogether from inside the style div (but left the word style="") and it still didn't break.

Answer (score 3):

Wrapping the word *imagination* in another `.span` with `display: inline-block` applied to it might solve it. See the example below

```js
    var button = document.body.querySelector('.changeWidth');
    var textWrap = document.body.querySelector('.text-wrap');

    button.addEventListener('click', changeWidth);

    function changeWidth() {
      textWrap.style.width = (Math.random() * (600 - 200) + 200) + 'px';
    }
```

```css
 body {
   font: 2em bold Arial, sans-serif;
 }
 div.text-wrap {
   width: 250px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
 }
 span.word-wrap {
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<div class="text-wrap">

  <span class="word-wrap">The Clore Prize</span>  <span class="word-wrap"><span style="text-decoration: underline; color: rgb(247, 147, 30);">i</span>mag<span style="text-decoration: underline; color: rgb(85, 81, 163);">i</span>nat<span style="text-decoration: underline; color: rgb(238, 65, 34);">i</span>on</span>
  <span
  class="word-wrap">lab</span>

</div>

<button class="changeWidth">Change width of container</button>
```